# solve recursion $T(n) = T(\alpha n)+T(\beta n)+\gamma n$

Tags: recursion

I need solve this recursion:
$$T(n) = T(\alpha n)+T(\beta n)+\gamma n$$
I know that for $\alpha +\beta< 1$ solution is $O(n)$

How is for $\alpha + \beta = 1$ and $\alpha + \beta > 1$?

Comment: Are there any theorems at your disposal? What are your thoughts? It is important to give as much context as possible so that users can best formulate their answers.

Comment: To solve this problem we can use recursion tree. For α+β<1 I saw some lecture. For  α+β=1 I've just  found solution but how is about α+β>1? http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs360/recursion_tree_method.pdf

Comment: For $\alpha+\beta > 1$, are you sure this is well-defined? (at least, ask that $\alpha < 1$ and $\beta < 1$)

Comment: What are the conventions here:  $T$ is defined for real numbers?  Or if defined for integers, what to do when $\alpha n$ is not an integer?

Comment: @Clement C. You are right. So  1<α+β<2

Comment: @GEdgar I's cost of algorithm

Comment: Generally "solve recursion" means to write a function non recursively.  What you are asking for is the asymptotic behavior of a function, completely different.

Comment: My fault. I want sth like this http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/prac-quiz1-sol.pdf page 3

Comment: Or here is better explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090361/recursive-tree-with-constant-tn-tn-3-t2n-3-cn

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Leighton's ["Notes on Better Master Theorems for Divide-and-Conquer Recurrences"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc_view/pid/513611099c8ba4c5b8b878af143641175fe351b0) (1996).

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you suspect something you should simply substitute it $T(n)=knG(n)$. So we have

$$knG(n)=kn\alpha G(\alpha n)+kn\beta G(\beta n) + \gamma n$$

and this gives

$$G(n)=\alpha G(\alpha n)+\beta G(\beta n) + \frac{\gamma}{k}$$

This recursion cannot have any other solution than constant (if it is to have any solution at all) $G(n)=c$ and it is even strict what constant it must be

$$c=\frac{\gamma}{k(1-\alpha-\beta)}$$

If $\alpha + \beta = 1$ then it must be $\gamma = 0$ if we want to have at least one solution.

So the solution is

$$ T(n)=n\frac{\gamma}{1-\alpha-\beta}, \; \alpha+\beta \neq 1 $$
$$ T(n)=kn, \; \alpha+\beta = 1, \; \gamma = 0 $$

This makes it $O(n)$ whatever it takes but you cannot neglect restrictions, if you want to have any solution, and in the case $\alpha+\beta = 1$ although still linear $k$ can be as large as you like. Similar if $\alpha+\beta$ is very close to 1.